# How to trigger window.reload before page loads completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I am trying to perform an action  whenever a webpage gets refreshed. I am using `window.onload` to trigger the action, but the problem is `window.onload` waits too long to finish everything.

Is there any way to fire `window.onload` a little bit earlier, or another method which could be used on reload of a web page?

Comment: so... on reload, you want to reload? wouldn't that cause a redirect loop?

Comment: I am sorry  its not window.reload but window.onload   (my mistake :-)   ]

Comment: Do you want any elements to load before you run the code? Otherwise you can just call the function right away, without using window.onload

Comment: Actually   Once page load  elementId value changes with user click and to hold the same element value I use window.location.hash to retrive same id value using window.onload but it works after page loads completely which is too slow for user.